# Cant access variables assigned in OnPreRender in a click event

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-web-part, events

Im trying to break down a problem Ive been having for several days. And I think it comes down too the code below. When I assign stuff in OnPreRender, I cant access them with my click event. What am I doing wrong?, I would really appreciate some help on this :/

```
    Label debug;
    Button btn;
    SPWeb curweb;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        btn = new Button();
        debug = new Label();
        btn.Text = "updateview";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(updateAllProducts_Click);

        this.Controls.Add(debug);
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        EnsureChildControls();

        curweb = SPContext.Current.Web;
    }

    void updateAllProducts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (curweb == null)
        {
            debug.Text += " curweb is null "; //why is curweb null? :(
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, get familiar with the Page Life-Cycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(VS.100).aspx

The OnPreRender occurs after PostBack events. You shall move your code to OnLoad method and there initialize variables.

Comment: yes, you are correct